# RxJS - dispatch an action from the component constructor

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs, observable

I want to dispatch an action from the component constructor.

```
static dispatchAction(props) {
    if(props && props.key && props.key.innerKey) {
        Rx.Observable.of(ac.setInnerKey(props.key.innerKey));
    }
}
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  Componentt.dispatchAction(props);
}
```

This is the key I have in my reducer:

```
export const ac: acType= {
    setInnerKey: key => {
        return {
            type: actionTypes.SET_INNER_KEY,
            innerKey: key
        };
    }
};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SET_INNER_KEY: {
            return {
                ...state,
                innerKey: {...action.innerKey}
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

The `setInnerKey` function is being called correctly, however the reducer is not getting the`SET_INNER_KEY` action. I registered my reducer and all correctly.

How to make sure the action is dispatched correctly so that the reducer gets it?

Comment: is your reducer getting called and what is the shape of your action.key

Comment: reducer is getting called, however this action is not getting dispatched. I could see other actions coming to switch statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dispatchAction` method is not dispatching any action. You are calling the action creator method `acType.setInnerKey` but the return value of this method, which is the action object, is not being dispatched at all.

You have to invoke redux's `dispatch` method with the output of `acType.setInnerKey` method as argument.

If you are using `react-redux`, you can access the dispatch method using `mapDispatchToProps` function. If you need more information on `mapDispatchToProps`, refer https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options